# PKIX path building failed in only one environment

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, websphere

I have a java class that connects with a SSL webservice.

I am using Websphere 7.0.0.0, I have deployed it to 4 servers with no problem. I've been added the certificate using Websphere "Retrieve from port" and have not had any issue.

But just when I try to deploy to Production, I am not able. Nor have been able to reproduce the same issue in any other server.

Here (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21651084) I found that *“With earlier versions of WebSphere Application Server like 6.1 and 7.0.0.0 - 7.0.0.15 the retrieve from port feature would retrieve the signer to the leaf certificate instead of the root certificate if there was a chain of certificates. “*. I checked the version in Prod and was the **7.0.0.23**, so it made sanse to me and upgraded one of my environments, but while testing, everything was working fine there.

I used also `AdminTask.extractConfigProperties('[-propertiesFileName ConfigProperties_server1.props -configData Server=server1]')` to export all properties form both Websphere configurations but everything seems pretty standarized between both.

Any ideas on what should I compare to get a little bit closer to what could be the difference?

Here is the log of production with the certificate imported using WebSpehre's "retrieve from port"

```
[8/10/16 15:14:24:454 PDT] 00000025 ClassName >>> AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:22)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:423)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:192)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:176)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:53)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:464)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.s(kb.java:545)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:530)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:79)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:437)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:142)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:686)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:113)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:61)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.a(e.java:22)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.a(pc.java:100)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.checkServerTrusted(pc.java:15)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.core.WSX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(WSX509TrustManager.java:358)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:5)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:411)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:258)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:98)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.&lt;init&gt;(BasicChecker.java:111)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.java:176)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.myValidator(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:737)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:649)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:357)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.security.cert.CertPathUtil.findIssuer(CertPathUtil.java:298)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.&lt;init&gt;(BasicChecker.java:108)
    ... 48 more

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:SERVER1

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:154)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:22)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:423)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:192)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:176)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:53)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:464)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.s(kb.java:545)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:530)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:79)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:437)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:142)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:686)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:113)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:61)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.a(e.java:22)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.a(pc.java:100)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.checkServerTrusted(pc.java:15)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.core.WSX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(WSX509TrustManager.java:358)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:5)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:411)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:258)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:98)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.<init>(BasicChecker.java:111)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.java:176)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.myValidator(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:737)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:649)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:357)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.security.cert.CertPathUtil.findIssuer(CertPathUtil.java:298)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.<init>(BasicChecker.java:108)
    ... 48 more
```

And here is the code when I delete the certificate, it should be exactly the same if nothing was imported, right?

```
[8/10/16 15:03:58:401 PDT] 00000023 WSX509TrustMa E   CWPKI0022E: SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE:  A signer with SubjectDN "CN=<CERT>, OU=xxx, O=xxx, STREET=xx, L=xx, ST=xx, POSTALCODE=xx, C=US, SERIALNUMBER=xx, OID.2.5.4.15=xx, OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=xx, OID.1xx" was sent from target host:port "xxx:000".  The signer may need to be added to local trust store "D:/..." located in SSL configuration alias "xxx" loaded from SSL configuration file "security.xml".  The extended error message from the SSL handshake exception is: "PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error".
[8/10/16 15:03:58:401 PDT] 00000023 SystemOut     O 
[8/10/16 15:03:58:401 PDT] 00000023 SystemOut     O CWPKI0022E: SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE:  A signer with SubjectDN "CN=<CERT>, OU=xxx, O=xxx, STREET=xx, L=xx, ST=xx, POSTALCODE=xx, C=US, SERIALNUMBER=xx, OID.2.5.4.15=xx, OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=xx, OID.1xx" was sent from target host:port "xxx:000".  The signer may need to be added to local trust store "D:/..." located in SSL configuration alias "xxx" loaded from SSL configuration file "security.xml".  The extended error message from the SSL handshake exception is: "PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error".
[8/10/16 15:03:58:401 PDT] 00000023 SystemOut     O 
[8/10/16 15:03:58:401 PDT] 00000023 SystemOut     O 
[8/10/16 15:03:58:401 PDT] 00000023 SystemOut     O CWPKI0428I: 
The signer might need to be added to the local trust store. You can use the Retrieve from port option in the administrative 
console to retrieve the certificate and resolve the problem. If you determine that the request is trusted, complete the following steps: 
1. Log into the administrative console.  2. Expand Security and click SSL certificate and key management. 
Under Configuration settings, click Manage endpoint security configurations. 
3. Select the appropriate outbound configuration to get to the (cell):xxx:(node):xxx management scope. 
4. Under Related Items, click Key stores and certificates and click the NodeDefaultTrustStore key store. 
5. Under Additional Properties, click Signer certificates and  Retrieve From Port. 
 6. In the Host field, enter <CERT> in the host name field, 
 enter 443 in the Port field, and xxxcert in the Alias field. 
 7. Click Retrieve Signer Information.  8. Verify that the certificate information is for a certificate that you can trust. 
 9. Click Apply and Save.
[8/10/16 15:03:58:401 PDT] 00000023 SystemOut     O 
[8/10/16 15:03:58:401 PDT] 00000025 WSX509TrustMa E   CWPKI0022E: SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE:  A signer with SubjectDN "CN=<CERT>, OU=xxx, O=xxx, STREET=xx, L=xx, ST=xx, POSTALCODE=xx, C=US, SERIALNUMBER=xx, OID.2.5.4.15=xx, OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=xx, OID.1xx" was sent from target host:port "xxx:000".  The signer may need to be added to local trust store "D:/..." located in SSL configuration alias "xxx" loaded from SSL configuration file "security.xml".  The extended error message from the SSL handshake exception is: "PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error".
[8/10/16 15:03:58:417 PDT] 00000025  >>> AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:22)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:423)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:192)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:176)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:53)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:464)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.s(kb.java:545)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:530)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:79)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:437)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:142)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:686)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:113)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:61)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.a(e.java:22)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.a(pc.java:100)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.checkServerTrusted(pc.java:15)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.core.WSX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(WSX509TrustManager.java:358)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:5)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:411)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:258)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:98)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.&lt;init&gt;(BasicChecker.java:111)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.java:176)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.myValidator(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:737)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:649)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:357)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.security.cert.CertPathUtil.findIssuer(CertPathUtil.java:298)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.&lt;init&gt;(BasicChecker.java:108)
    ... 48 more

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:SERVER1

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:154)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:22)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:423)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:192)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:176)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:53)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:464)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.s(kb.java:545)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:530)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:79)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:437)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:142)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:686)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:113)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:61)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.a(e.java:22)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.a(pc.java:100)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.checkServerTrusted(pc.java:15)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.core.WSX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(WSX509TrustManager.java:358)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:5)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:411)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:258)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:98)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.<init>(BasicChecker.java:111)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.java:176)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.myValidator(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:737)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:649)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:357)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.security.cert.CertPathUtil.findIssuer(CertPathUtil.java:298)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.<init>(BasicChecker.java:108)
    ... 48 more
```

Any help or hint is extremely appreciated

**Update:**

Using `certutil -f -urlfetch -verify "C:\<file>.crt"` I got this information:

```
...
...
CertContext[0][2]: dwInfoStatus=10c dwErrorStatus=0
  Issuer: CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  NotBefore: 11/7/2006 5:00 PM
  NotAfter: 7/16/2036 4:59 PM
  Subject: CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Serial: 1234
  4e b6 d5 78 ....
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_NAME_MATCH_ISSUER (0x4)
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_IS_SELF_SIGNED (0x8)
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_PREFERRED_ISSUER (0x100)
  ----------------  Certificate AIA  ----------------
  No URLs "None" Time: 0
  ----------------  Certificate CDP  ----------------
  No URLs "None" Time: 0
  ----------------  Certificate OCSP  ----------------
  No URLs "None" Time: 0
  --------------------------------
  Application[0] = 1.3.. Server Authentication
  Application[1] = 1.3.. Client Authentication
  Application[2] = 1.3.. Secure Email
  Application[3] = 1.3.. Code Signing

**Exclude leaf cert:**
  64 45 47 5b ......
Full chain:
  f7 4b 3b c5 ......
------------------------------------
Verified Issuance Policies:
    2.23...
    2.16...
Verified Application Policies:
    1.3.6... Server Authentication
    1.3.6.. Client Authentication
Cert is an End Entity certificate
**Leaf certificate revocation check passed**
CertUtil: -verify command completed successfully.
```

If the **Leaf is excluded**, how can I add it? I asked for it and the issuers sent me a .key, and a SHA-2 .txt for the "intermediate".

Comment: You wouldn't need the Leaf certificate. SSL certificates are usually chained together as A-B-C. So, A is validated by B and B is validated by C. If you have C in your trust store, the entire thing should be validated properly. Try hitting the web service URL with a browser, extract the certificate and verify that the root certificate is what you have in your trust store.